# Proof Verification and Help: Proving $b^n$ converges to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing

Claim: $b^n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for $0<b<1$

Proof:
Let $ \epsilon \gt0$ be given.

Rough work:

$|b^n| = b^n \lt \epsilon$ $ \implies n\gt\frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln b}$

Set $N = \frac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln b}$

We want to show that $ \forall n\gt N, |b^n - 0|\lt\epsilon$

Then:

I'm confused as to how to approach further than this and show that $b^n <\epsilon$

Can anyone please help in how to proceed after this and conclude my proof?

Thank you.

Comment: What is the value of $b$?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to specify it...  0<b<1. Will edit my question.

Comment: $N$ is supposed to be a natural number but your choice of $N$ is not necessarily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to order things slightly differently.

Fix $\epsilon>0$. Choose $N>\dfrac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln b}$. Then whenever $n>N$, $b^n<b^N=\epsilon$ (note that $b^n<b^N$ since $b\in(0,1)$).

Since this works for every $\epsilon>0$, $b^n\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Will this work :  Choose $N = \dfrac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln b}$ Then, for any n>N $ \implies$ $n> \dfrac{\ln\epsilon}{\ln b} \implies$ $b^n < \epsilon$

Comment: @A.Asad Yes, that works

Comment: The choice of $N$ is not necessarily a positive integer in this post. It should be revised to "choose $N > \tfrac{ \ln \epsilon}{\ln b}$" or make use of the ceiling function; $N=\lceil \tfrac{ \ln \epsilon}{\ln b} \rceil$.

Comment: I'll go with $N > \tfrac{ \ln \epsilon}{\ln b}$. Also, would the > sign be more appropriate than = in proofs related to convergence?

Comment: @A.Asad We can do either here, as in Love's comment

Answer (score 1):

Since $0<b<1$, write
$$
\frac{1}{b}=1+t
$$
with $t>0$. Then
$$
\frac{1}{b^n}=(1+t)^n\ge 1+nt
$$
by Bernoulli’s inequality. This implies
$$
b^n\le\frac{1}{1+nt}
$$
Since
$$
\frac{1}{1+nt}<\varepsilon
$$
is equivalent to
$$
n>\frac{\varepsilon^{-1}-1}{t}
$$
we can conclude.